# I want to display data based on two Picker input in React Native

Tags: react-native, onclick, picker

**I have two picker and a Button.**

```
const picker1Items = [
  { label: "x1", value: 'x1' },
  { label: "y1", value: 'y1' },
  { label: "z1", value: 'z1' },
];
```

*and*

```
const picker2Items = [
  { label: "x2", value: 'x2' },
  { label: "y2", value: 'y2' },
  { label: "z2", value: 'z2' },
];
```

How can I **Onclick** display specific result for the selected picker?

Say, If I have selected ***x1*** and ***z2*** from **two picker**, *Onclick* of the **button** I want it to output *value1*

| Picker 1 | Picker 2 | Onclick of the button |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | x2 | v1 |
| x1 | y2 | v2 |
| x1 | z2 | v3 |
| y1 | x2 | v4 |
| y1 | y2 | v5 |
| y1 | z2 | v6 |
| z1 | z2 | v7 |
| z1 | y2 | v8 |
| z1 | z2 | v9 |

How Can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is psuedo code for how this can be accomplished. You will want to lift the values and store them in state somewhere. In this example, I am using hooks and local component state. Then with those values set you'll create the computed value to display.

```
const [picker1Value, setPicker1Value] = useState(null)

const [picker2Value, setPicker2Value] = useState(null)

const computedValue = useMemo(() => picker1Value + picker2Value, [picker1Value, picker2Value]);

<Picker values={picker2Items} value={picker1Value} onClick={setPicker1Value} />

<Picker values={picker2Items} value={picker2Value} onClick={setPicker2Value} />

<Text>{computedValue}</Text>
```